# Information on setters and getters

Tags: android, android-listview

I am learning extensively about getters and setters but I seem not to be having my way.
I have a class called Apps_Info which contains my setters and getters and I have my main activity FavouriteApps that has a list which uses the class Apps_Info.
I am trying to get the name of the package from the List in FavouriteApps but I am still getting null.
Please can someone tell what to do? Below is the code in this order: class Apps_Info and FavouriteApps activity

```
public class Apps_Info {
    private Bitmap bIcon;
    private String sName;
    private String sPacks_Name;

    public Apps_Info(Bitmap icon, String name, String Packs_Name) {
        bIcon = icon;
        sName = name;
        sPacks_Name = Packs_Name;
    }

    public void setIcon(Bitmap icon) {
        bIcon=icon;
    }

    public Bitmap getIcon() {
        return bIcon;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        sName=name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return sName;
    }

    public void setPacks_Name(String Packs_Name) {
        this.sPacks_Name=Packs_Name;
    }

    public String getPacks_Name() {
        return sPacks_Name;
    }
}
```

FavouriteApps Activity code (part)

```
String packname, packsname, apps_names;
Bitmap app_icon; 
Resources res = getResources();
List<Apps_Info> ListApps_Info = new ArrayList<Apps_Info>();
ListApps_Info.add(new Apps_Info(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.browser_app), "Browser", "com.browser"));
ListApps_Info.add(new Apps_Info(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.clock_app), "Alarm Clock", "com.alarm.clock"));
ListApps_Info.add(new Apps_Info(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.threegplus), "3G Secure Connection", "threeg.secureconnect"));

mGridView.setAdapter(new Apps_Info_Adapter(this, ListApps_Info));
Apps_Info packinfo = new Apps_Info(app_icon, apps_names, packname);
packsname = packinfo.getPacks_Name();
apps_names = packinfo.getName();
Log.i("The Pack_Name is " + packsname, "Pack Name");
```

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2003/jw-0905-toolbox.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ListApps_Info.size(); i++) {
    Apps_Info packinfo = ListApps_Info.item(i);
    packsname = packinfo.getPacks_Name();
    apps_names = packinfo.getName();
    Log.i("The Pack_Name is " + packsname, "Pack Name");
}
```

Comment: Sergey thanks for the answer it answered my question but a little problem is that there is no item() in the drop down from ListApps_Info, so I used get() but i am not getting the whole result that i need. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you never initialize the `packname` variable in your code.

```
 String packname,packsname,apps_names;
```

When you do this :

```
 Apps_Info packinfo=new Apps_Info(app_icon, apps_names,packname);
 packsname=packinfo.getPacks_Name();
```

your getter is doing well and this is normal if it returns null.

Comment: But what I want initialized to it is already in the List
       ListApps_Info.add(new Apps_Info(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.browser_app), "Browser", "com.browser"));

Comment: Wonder this compiles at all.   At Least IDEA would complain loudly about use of uniniotialized variable

Comment: So you may be you will try to do this :

for(Apps_Info current : ListApps_Info){
    packsname = current.getPacks_Name();
    apps_names = current.getName();
    Log.i("The Pack_Name is " + packsname, "Pack Name");
}

Comment: I want the packsname to always get the value from the list together with the apps_name.